# serverless-openwhisk Package Configuration does not include files

Tags: serverless-framework, openwhisk

I am trying to individually package my openwhisk actions using the serverless framework. My action simply prints out all files and directories from "./"

My problem is, I can't find the included files "workflow.js" and "workflow.json" anywhere. Are they even included at all? The src directory does not contain the files either, it only contains a file called "service.js"

```
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856352769Z stdout: .dockerignore",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856367445Z stdout: 5u3RVNXU",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856373403Z stdout: CHANGELOG.md",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856379151Z stdout: README.md",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856385821Z stdout: Vr6M5n51",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.8566812Z   stdout: app.js",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856696174Z stdout: node_modules",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856702235Z stdout: package-lock.json",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856707997Z stdout: package.json",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856714673Z stdout: runner.js",
"2018-07-01T12:43:39.856974881Z stdout: src"
```

My serverless.yml looks like this:

```
service: private-cloud

provider:
  name: openwhisk
  versionFunctions: false
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - node_modules/**
    - workflow.js
    - workflow.json

functions:
  action1:
    handler: handler1.hello
    name: action1Handler
    package:
      include:
        - handler1.js
  action2:
    handler: handler2.hello
    name: action2Handler
    package:
      include:
        - handler2.js
    events: # All events associated with this function
      - http: POST /api/${self:functions.action2.name}
  action3:
    handler: handler3.hello
    name: action3Handler
    package:
      include:
        - handler3.js
  action4:
    handler: handler4.hello
    name: action4Handler
    package:
      include:
        - handler4.js
  action5:
    handler: handler5.hello
    name: action5Handler
    package:
      include:
        - handler5.js
    events: # All events associated with this function
      - http: POST /api/${self:functions.action5.name}

# Add the serverless-openwhisk plugin
# https://github.com/serverless/plugins
plugins:
  - serverless-openwhisk
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is known an issue open https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-runtime-nodejs/issues/57

To find the root of the src from the zip use nodejs variable __dirname

Like 
    let filePath = __dirname + “/workflow.json”

Comment: Thank you!! That helps a lot. Unfortuantely, the directory only only includes one of the files, the JS file. The other one, the JSON, is not included. But this is more a problem with the serverless-framework, I guess.

Comment: I found the issue :) It was on my side. Thanks again csantanapr